# Python's new `functools.cached_property` bug or limitation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since Python 3.8, `functools` has a `cached_property`. 
I've been using a similar `lazyprop` decorator based on Beazley's cookbook (code below), but when I replace by the builtin, I get problems. Here's one of them.

When I use the decorator within the class definition, using the `@` operator, it doesn't complain.

But if I use it with `setattr`, I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot use cached_property instance without calling __set_name__ on it.
```

Beazley's simple version works fine though.

```py
from functools import cached_property

class lazyprop:
    """Based on code from David Beazley's "Python Cookbook"."""
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.__doc__ = getattr(func, '__doc__')
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            value = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
            return value

class D:
    def __init__(self, greeting='Hello'):
        self.greeting = greeting

def greet(self):
    return self.greeting + " world!"


# Beazley's version works...
D.greet = lazyprop(greet)
assert D().greet == "Hello world!"

# ... but the builtin version will fail
D.greet = cached_property(greet)
# D().greet  # this will fail
```

Comment: can you just try like given in this example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-functools-cached_property/

Comment: What is your question? The error pretty clearly states it expects to have its ``__set_name__`` method called. The two just work *differently*, for example  ``cached_property`` can also be used with anonymous functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR The cache is the instance dict itself, and the name of the property is needed as the key. The chosen design imposes the limitation, but (IMO) it's a good compromise. `lazyprop` is not thread-safe, or at least may call `self.func` more than is strictly necessary in a multi-threaded environment.

---

To start, it is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) that `__set_name__` is only called if the assignment occurs in the context of type creation. The note in the documentation (adapted to your example) shows what you need to do: call `__set_name__` yourself.

```
class D:
    def __init__(self, greeting='Hello'):
        self.greeting = greeting

    def greet(self):
        return self.greeting + " world!"

D.greet = cached_property(greet)
D.greet.__set_name__(D, 'greet')  # sets D.greet.attrname = "greet" for later use

assert D().greet == "hello world!"
```

Why is the attribute name needed? `cached_property.__set__` is not defined, so given `d = D()`, `d.greet` will first look for an instance attribute named `greet` in `d.__dict__`. If it is not found, then `D.greet.__get__(d, D)` will be called. That function basically does three things: it calls the original `greet` function *if needed* to compute the value, then saves it to a new instance attribute with the same name, and then returns the computed value.

"*Wait*", you ask, "*what do you mean, 'if needed'? Didn't you just say `D.greet.__get__` is only called if the instance attribute doesn't already exist?*" Yes, but in a multithreaded environment, you don't know if another thread might *also* be executing `D.greet.__get__` at the same time. In order to prevent a race condition, `__get__` goes through the following steps (you can follow along [in the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/functools.py#L947) if you like):

1. Check for an instance attribute with the same name, in case it was created in another thread after the current call started.
2. If not, try to get a lock so we can create the instance attribute ourselves.
3. Once you get the lock, look for the instance attribute *again*, in case someone created it while we waited for the lock.
4. If the instance attribute *still* does not exist, we can safely create it ourselves.
5. Finally, whether we pulled a value from the instance attribute or called the original `greet` function ourselves, we can return the value.

With all this in mind, I would call this a limitation rather than a bug, but a limitation that is easily worked around. This implementation is probably simpler than one that tries not to rely on the name of the property itself for maintaining the necessary mapping.

Comment: Excellent. Clear and complete. You win, @chepner. I do wonder... If the only risk of `lazyprop` is when threading, and the only effect is calling the function more than it needs to, I think `lazyprop` wins on average performance since `cached_property` adds an **constant** overhead over `lazyprop`, to save an **occasional** function call. Wouldn't you say?

Comment: The question is: is the overhead so prohibitive that you feel the need to introduce your own code (that needs to be tested and updated) rather than reusing something already in the standard library?

Answer (score 1):

This is neither a bug nor a limitation. Using `__set_name__` is merely a different means to deduce the property name - one that is more robust when used with regular class syntax.

For example, `__set_name__` also works for anonymous functions with only the `cached_property` bound directly to a name:

```py
from functools import cached_property
import random

class Bar:
    foo = cached_property(lambda self: random.random())
    
bar = Bar()
print(bar.foo)  # 0.9901613829744336
print(bar.foo)  # 0.9901613829744336
```

When using `cached_property.cached_property` instead, the value is stored improperly – namely as `bar.<lambda>` – preventing it from shadowing the property.

```py
>>> functools_bar.__dict__
{'foo': 0.9901613829744336}
>>> cached_property_bar.__dict__
{'<lambda>': 0.7003011051281254}
```

Comment: +1 For a well chosen minimal example. Thanks. But @chepner's answer provides both thorough explanation and work around solution, so he/she wins.